# Compile metafun book with ConText (getting a cover-like)

Tags: context, metafun

Anyone knowns how to create (please sample code) a cover page like this?:

http://context.aanhet.net/general/manuals/metafun-p.pdf

The sources are available from:
http://context.aanhet.net/svn/manuals/metafun/

BUT, i'm unable to compile (ConText) doing `context metafun.tex` ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

`metafun.rb` tells you what to do:

```
# usage: runtools metafun.rb
```

`runtools` is a ruby script and located as `runtools.rb` in TeXLive at

```
/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/
```

So you can run

```
ruby /usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/scripts/context/ruby/runtools.rb metafun.rb
```

Or creating a `runtools` in an executable directory as a link to the `runtools.rb`.

After a while you'll get a new pdf `metafun.pdf` if, of course, you have installed the `ruby` system.

A call like `context ...` can't work because `metafun` needs an older version to run:

```
texexec --pdf --automp --suffix="-p" metafun
```

alkso called `ConTeXt MKII`

Comment: “A call like context ... can't work because metafun needs an older version to run:” Have you checked this? Invoking ``pdfinfo`` on the print version (``metafun-p.pdf``) I get “Producer:       LuaTeX-0.63.0”.

Comment: I cannot see a matafun-p.pdf in the above directory. Maybe it is created with `context` but then with another script. And as far as I can see `context metafun` doesn't work.

Comment: I am referring to the manuals available [on the Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Metafun) (the ``-p`` and ``-s`` suffixes indicate the print and screen version respectively).
If the sources don’t build with MkIV then perhaps Hans has an updated copy of the sources lying around somewhere, so OP should ask on the mailing list. (Disclaimer: I never tried to build the metafun manual from source myself.)